# How can I change the layout order with one button?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout, layoutparams

I've create one layout with 3 `RelativeLayout` includes. 2 of these are invisible and I want to make them visible and to the top when I press one button. Is it possible?

How can I make android:

```
layout_below="@id/pag6a_1"
```

programmatically?

---

it makes me an error!! this is my code: `protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.pag6a);

```
    RelativeLayout pag6a_2 = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.pag6a_2);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) pag6a_2.getLayoutParams();

    pag6a_2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.pag6a_3);`
```

---

..and this is my logcat:

> 10-10 21:27:11.025: E/AndroidRuntime(3117): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   10-10 21:27:11.025: E/AndroidRuntime(3117): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.beandroid.pirani/com.beandroid.pirani.Pag6A}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams
>   10-10 21:27:11.025: E/AndroidRuntime(3117):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
>   10-10 21:27:11.025: E/AndroidRuntime(3117):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
>   10-10 21:27:11.025: E/AndroidRuntime(3117):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
>   10-10 21:27:11.025: E/AndroidRuntime(3117):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
>   10-10 21:27:11.025: E/AndroidRuntime(3117):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   10-10 21:27:11.025: E/AndroidRuntime(3117):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>   10-10 21:27:11.025: E/AndroidRuntime(3117):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
>   10-10 21:27:11.025: E/AndroidRuntime(3117):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   10-10 21:27:11.025: E/AndroidRuntime(3117):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>   10-10 21:27:11.025: E/AndroidRuntime(3117):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
>   10-10 21:27:11.025: E/AndroidRuntime(3117):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
>   10-10 21:27:11.025: E/AndroidRuntime(3117):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   10-10 21:27:11.025: E/AndroidRuntime(3117): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams
>   10-10 21:27:11.025: E/AndroidRuntime(3117):     at com.beandroid.pirani.Pag6A.onCreate(Pag6A.java:44)
>   10-10 21:27:11.025: E/AndroidRuntime(3117):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
>   10-10 21:27:11.025: E/AndroidRuntime(3117):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
>   10-10 21:27:11.025: E/AndroidRuntime(3117):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
>   10-10 21:27:11.025: E/AndroidRuntime(3117):     ... 11 more

Answer (score 1):

I guess you're looking for something like this.-

```
RelativeLayout yourLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.yourLayoutId);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) yourLayout.getLayoutParams();
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.pag6a_1);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I get the question right it's better to have a `Linearlayout`. inside of that a `ViewFlipper` and a `button` set the `RelativeLayout` inside of `ViewFlipper`.

```
ViewFlipper fliper = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.viewFlipperid);
```

and in button's `onClick` add `flipper.showNext'.